# How to check for user data on a oauth protected rest service from second application which has spring security?

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have a REST application secured with oauth2 (A1) and another one (A2) which calls the A1 for login and in general for data.

The problem is that for login I don't want to call A2 for a user entity and register it in A1 (which has spring security integrated => I need to register credential data including password into it)

I think making a REST call to A2 (send userid and get  user with role and password) is not a solution because is not secure. Anyone can call A2 with an id and get all user data including password and role.

What is the approach here? How can I get the user stuff to register it in spring security (integrated in A1)? And I don't want A1 to connect to the same db as A2

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood correctly, but I think you want to authenticate the user into A2 using the same authentication you use on A1.

You may use SSO (Single Sign-On) to authenticate in both A1 and A2. 
Spring Security OAuth provides the means to do that: https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/03/sso-with-oauth2-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-v